# Cached model only, no ActiveRecord. Best practice?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stripe-payments

Good afternoon all!

Here's the background.  I'm building a backend for a payment system.  I want the canonical information for our Products and Plans to be on Stripe.  As such I do not want to have a duplicated copy on our backend and pull them down from our RDB with ActiveRecord.

When someone calls for a list of Products or Plans I pull them down from Stripe, and then cache them.  When we need to create/update/destroy them we make the API calls to Stripe and the webhooks trigger the updates.

I've not done something like this before, and normally just have an ActiveRecords model to CRUD.

Are there any best practices / methodologies to follow when doing something like this?

Thanks!

Comment: You're probably going to get flagged because this question is both overly broad and opinion based. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Answer (score 1):

While it would be technically possible, I recommend against doing this in almost all cases. Your products are likely an integral part of your app. You will loose out on a lot of the idiomatic rails behaviors and abilities by trying to roll your own logic in this way. You'll also be coupling your app very tightly with a third party service that you in no way control.

I would seriously consider using standard AR backed models for this data in your app and taking the time to abstract out code that manages the YOUR APP <--> 3RD PARTY APP communication. This way your app is the canonical source of the information it manages, you get all of the rails' sugar, and you're in control in the event that you need to change back end providers.

Comment: Thanks for the input!  After prodding this for a bit I came to the same conclusion.  Building in the functionality for these classes was super redundant.